# Windows8: device identifier

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I am currently trying to retrieve a unique device identifier. Here is my code:

```
var token = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.getPackageSpecificToken(null);
var reader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.fromBuffer(token.id);

reader.unicodeEncoding = true;
var identifier = reader.readString(reader.unconsumedBufferLength);

console.log(identifier);
```

But it raises following error:

> The operation attempted to access data outside the valid range.

How can I retrieve the size of my *token.id* string? I also tried to use *token.id.length*, but result is the same.

Comment: Depending on what you are using it for, you should be aware that the id will change, possibly frequently on some devices.  You should probably use a subset of the constituent components in the id if you need to (more) reliably identify the device again later. Docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't try to replicate what you're doing at the moment, but you might try reading it as bytes into array like this:

```
var array = new Array(token.id.length);
reader.readBytes(array);
```

And then convert the array to a string for the identifier.

See these posts for examples:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1e2175e3-fe07-4094-9454-b3ecf1bf0381
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/cdf72b9f-b3c0-488e-b607-b4445a5039b3

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thanks for your help, even if I still can't get the reason why they return a IBuffer object instead of a simple string. But sure they got one. ;)