# Get stable unique device id for Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, winjs

So there are various posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057069/windows8-device-identifier) about getting a unique identifier for a Windows 8 device.  However, it is also recognised that the identifier changes when various system components change. From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx):

> Hardware drift is the reason why the app should not consume the ASHWID byte  stream as is. If a few hardware components change or are switched off, the API  returns a different ASHWID. The app risks the possibility of incorrectly  identifying the same device as a new
>   device. Here are some plausible scenarios  that may cause hardware drift:
>
> - Towards the end of the day, a user wants to make the battery last until she gets home, so she switches off Bluetooth and Wi-Fi, while keeping 3G/4G on for connectivity with the cloud.
> - A user plugs in a USB 3G data card.
> - The underlying OS/System on Chip power management may switch off certain cores.

This is a pretty sorry state of affairs.  The docs recommend looking at the ASHWID (App Specific Hardware ID) and weighting various components that are less likely to change and ignoring (giving weight 0) to things that are variable, like whether a dock is present.  However, I don't see any docs on how to identify components.  The identifier I get back it just a list of numbers.

Is there a better way to get a stable unique device id (it's fine if it's package specific, as long as it's unique per device/package combo)? <s>Alternatively, can somebody point me to a doc on how to identify components within the token generated by `HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken`?</s>

**UPDATE:**

Worked out the components part. But still interested in a better way to get a stable id.

> The byte stream consists of multiple groups of four bytes. The first two bytes contain the type of the component and the next two bytes contain the value. Use the table below to identify the type of each component:

Comment: This article gives a code based solution to checking against hardware shift https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-ASHWID-to-3742c83e

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Receipts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.getappreceiptasync.aspx) API. The Docs indicate that it has a Device identifier "ReceiptDeviceId" under the "Receipt" element. The only issue being the API only works if the user is logged in to the store.

Comment: Definitely an interesting idea. I can guarantee my users will be online as my app requires an internet connection but I can't guarantee they will be logged into the store...

Comment: I've looked into this a bit and it seems `ReceiptDeviceId` is different for each run of my app. Do you know if this value is consistent with a published app, perhaps even between installs on the same device (vs using the `CurrentAppSimulator` class)?

Comment: from what I have seen, it is constant for a published app. the currentappsimulator just returns a random one every call.